# how to get a value from a edit control using coded UI test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to get an Order  number from a text field using coded UI TEST

The text field id  is :  ***order_no.***

***I know with selenium i would use:***

```
String strOrderNumber=driver.findElement(By.id("order_no")).getAttribute("value");
```

My code in codedUi test

```
public static void getOrderNumber(UITestControl Control) 
{ 
Control.TechnologyName = "web"; Control.SearchProperties.Add("Controltype", "Edit");
Control.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "order_no"); 
OrderNumber = Control.GetProperty("Text").ToString(); 
Console.Write(OrderNumber); 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v5zN.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What happened, what was correct and what was wrong. How did Coded UI's record and generate tool handle this field?

Comment: I am not doing Coded UI record and play back ,it won't be useful in my case because I am trying to get a value from a text field which is disable d .Please refer to the screenshot attached above .

Comment: Thanks , I got it.

Comment: public static void getOrderNumber(UITestControl Control)
        {
           
            Control.TechnologyName = "web";
            Control.SearchProperties.Add("Controltype", "Edit");
            Control.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "order_no");

            OrderNumber = Control.GetProperty("Text").ToString();
            Console.Write(OrderNumber);
        }

Comment: Please do not add lumps of unformatted code as comments. Please [edit] the question to show the code. Have you tried the record tool against that field? If not, why not? I do not think its enabled/disabled state is relevant. Copying ideas from auto-generated code is a good method of creating Coded UI tests.

Comment: @AbrahamDlamini Can you please confirm the property name in GetProperty("Text") is indeed corrct by checking the properties of control using coded UI test builder? Because as per my experince in lot of the cases the test value lies in "Innertext" or "valueattribute" property name and not "Text"